# Prevent scrolling from anchor tags

Tags: jquery, tabs, navigation, anchor

I'm making a simple navigation with jQuery that loads content panes by showing or hiding them on the page. I am using anchor tags to determine which pane to show. I also use a "ready" function to show the `#hash` element when the page is loaded. Pretty basic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video_form_content > div').hide();
  var showTab = window.location.hash || "#basic-info";
  $(showTab).show();
}

$('#video_form_tabs li').on('click', function() {
    $('#video_form_content > div').hide();
    var target = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    $(target).show();
})
```

What's happening, though, is that when the elements are clicked, the page jumps to the top of the target `div`. I don't want this jump, but I do want to keep the default functionality of the anchor tag in the sense that I want the hash added to the URL so that refreshing would reopen the same tab.

Here's what I've tried

- Adding `$(window).scrollTop(0)` to the click event. I thought it might, but this event fires before the actual navigation of the anchor element, so it's immediately undone.
- Adding `$(window).scrollTop(0)` to `$(document).ready()` However, this listener is not fired when clicking an anchor for the same page.
- Adding `window.location.hash = target` or `window.location.href = target` to the click event. However, this still causes the resubmission of the page, and it still "jumps".
- Adding `return false` to the function. This prevents adding the hash to the URL, which is highly preferred.

This is really baffling me, and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify your target `div`s with things like `#basic-info-TAB`, then add `"-TAB"` to the `target` variable.

Comment: Great suggestion, but this still causes a jump to the top of the page if the user is already scrolled some. +1 because I didn't think about trying that yet

Comment: Why does this work?  what does "-TAB" do to browsers?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retain the hash in the url, you have to manually add it

```
e.preventDefault(); // stop browser from following href
var url = $(this).prop('href'); // get href
var hash = url.split('#'); // get the hash-part
if(hash.length > 1) location.hash = hash[1]; // rewrite the url
```

I've only tested this in Chrome and it works great there.

Answer (score 2):

My method is to add a common class to the clickable elements, then do a setTimeout with a timeout of 0. In my case I added the class of "top" to my clickable elements.

```
$(".top").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 0);
})
```

You can set the x and y coordinates to whatever you like:

```
scrollTo(X, Y);
```

Quick and easy!

Do this to keep the current scroll position:

```
$(".top").click(function(){
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
    }, 0);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the event to the anchor and cancel the default event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video_form_content > div').hide();
  var showTab = window.location.hash || "#basic-info";
  $(showTab).show();
}

$('#video_form_tabs li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop browser from following href
    $('#video_form_content > div').hide();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).show();
})
```

Comment: Also having onclick="return false;" would prevent the default handler.

Comment: Except this doesn't add the hash to the end of the URL. And I already tried the return false, but that was a negative.

Comment: To prevent scrolling, you would have to set it to a non existing id and rebuild it later or, in alternative, use the HTML5 History API. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090478/jquery-hash-change-event