# Jquery Back Button.

Tags: jquery, back

I want to create a button which will run a previously ran function. ie i click buttonA to run Function A then click button B to run functionB i want to have a button which allows the user to go back to functionA by clicking a back button.

i thought i could a global variable to hold previous statements but it would not work as every function ran would overwrite the stored statements. here is some psuodo code to kind of explain what i mean

```
var globalvar;
globalvar = functionA;
function B { run globalvar};
```

Comment: Similar: [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25806608/55075) at SO

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use hash hyperlinks and the `hashchange` event. In jQuery:

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function() {
    var hash = location.hash.substring(1); // strip the leading # symbol
    // now run code based on whatever the value of 'hash' is
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#hash1">function A</a>
<a href="#hash2">function B</a>
```

Now, whenever the user clicks the browser's "back" button (or an HTML button that triggers `history.go(-1)`), it will go back to whatever hash was previously selected and trigger the hashchange event again.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/hL5FZ/

Warning: older browsers like IE7 [may not support hashchange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3090478/901048) or `history.go()`.

Comment: [Might find already existing history plugins in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin).

Comment: @bažmegakapa Yep, although if older browser support isn't needed, those plugins are probably overkill. I might use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for support and work around it for those rare cases instead.

Comment: Of course, just thought it's worth adding it as a comment. Sometimes you just don't want to reinvent the wheel :). Upvoted btw.

Answer (score 3):

JQuery method, and apply the class back to the link, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.back').click(function(){
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
  });
});
```