# how to use ajax and also have browser.back button

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm using ajax in my website and there is an ajax function that controls all links.

something like this:

```
function sendGet(url,dataform){
    $.post(url,{_ajax:1},function(data){
        $(dataform).html(data);
        window.location.hash = url;
    });
    return false;
}
```

and set hash with url.

alse I have this code in document load:

```
    var load_hash = window.setInterval(function(){
        if(window.location.hash) sendGet(window.location.hash.substr(1),"#include_content");
        clearInterval(load_hash);
    },1);
```

when back button is pressing I want to load the url in hash.

BUT most of the time it is not working.
it works sometimes when I refresh the page.

am I doing it right?

if not, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090478/jquery-hash-change-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event to the `window` object that listens to `hashchange`:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    sendGet(window.location.hash.substr(1),"#include_content");
});
```

That should work if you click the backbutton to load the correct page.