# jQuery hashtag: catch on load and listen to on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashtag

I am using jquery to get posts from the DB:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   loadPosts(limit,offset,category,sortby);

});
```

I want to use hashtag functionality to feed this functions with values. So if my url is **index.html#10&0&news&desc** I could catch it onload and split like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

       var hashString = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("&");
       loadPosts(hashString[0],hashString[1],hashString[2],hashString[3]);

});
```

It works fine as long as I supply my url with hashtags onload, *but how can I make it listen to "hashtag onChange"?*

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090478/jquery-hash-change-event

Comment: I use this plugin: [jQuery hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) with this [fix](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/pull/30/files).

Comment: or http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: Apply the fix y posted. That's because $.browser was removed from jQuery, so you have to change that line.

Comment: you're getting the 'msie undefined' error because $.borwser.msie was removed from jQuery as of version 1.6 (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) so if you want to use that plugin.... you might have to use an older version of jQuery