# How to trigger an event when hash location changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, fragment-identifier

I'm trying to trigger an event when the hash changes inside my url using the method `onhashchange`. I'm calling it, but it doesn't ever seem to get executed.

I've tried the following.

```
$(function () {
    window.addEventListener("onhashchange", function () {
        alert("Here");
    });

    window.onhashchange = function () {
        alert("Changed");
    }
)};
```

is there any reason why these functions aren't being called?

Comment: When you use `addEventListener` you don't put `on` at the beginning of the event name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090478/jquery-hashchange-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write 'hashchange' instead of 'onhashchange' in your first example.

This code works fine for me, at least in Chrome:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e){
    console.log('changed');
})
```

Here is short code-snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/bm8jjwmq/

Comment: I think that use if could be a good solution too http://jsbin.com/relumuzimu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}
```

▲ For Support // ▼ implementation

```
function locationHashChanged() {
    if (location.hash === "#somecoolfeature") {
        somecoolfeature();
    }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Comment: It should be a comment

Comment: To OP? I don't have enough reputation to comment. Apologies for the wrong spot.