# hashing and pushstate in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pushstate, hashchange

I have 3 buttons

```
 <div onclick="javascript:newmessage()" class="mailcontents">New Message</div>
<div onclick="javascript:inboxmails()" class="mailcontents">Inbox</div>
<div onclick="javascript:sentmailsbox()" class="mailcontents">Sent</div>
```

and the divs where the content has to be displayed

```
 <div id="inbox"></div>
<div id="sent"></div>
```

Onclick of each I am changing the content by calling the respective functions

```
    var times = 0;
   function inboxmails(){

       times++;
location.hash = times;
       $('#inbox').empty();
       $('#sent').empty();
       $('#newmessage').empty();
       $.ajax({
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#inbox').append('inbox data');

                }
            });
        }
   function sentmailsbox(){
       times++;
location.hash = times;
       $('#inbox').empty();
       $('#sent').empty();
       $('#newmessage').empty();
       $.ajax({
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#sent').append('sent data');

                }
            });

   }
   function newmessage(){
       $('#inbox').empty();
       $('#sent').empty();
       $('#newmessage').empty();
       $.ajax({
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#newmessage').append('new message data');

                }
            });

   }
```

I have also added hashing which adds hash tag and a numberical value to the url

Here is the plunker code **[*https://plnkr.co/edit/tTMzTFIHD03pkIt4CkHO?p=preview*](https://plnkr.co/edit/tTMzTFIHD03pkIt4CkHO?p=preview)**

But when I click on the back button of browser it must reload the previous ajax content. i.e, if I click on `inbox`, it displays `inbox data` and next I clicked on `sent`, it displays `sent data`, and then when I click the browser's back button it must display inbox content `inbox data` i.e, the previous content.

I understood how to change a url using hashing. But I am unable to understand and also could not find a proper example to pushstate i.e push history back / display the pervious ajax content.

I have checked various examples. But I am not understanding how to go to load ajax content using hashing.

Please help !!!
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You've not bound any function to a hashtag change event.  In JavaScript you could use this event to fire off the AJAX call again:

`window.onhashchange = doThisWhenTheHashChanges;`

See [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

There is also this JQuery [library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) you can look at which addresses cross browser compatibility issues and a full list of alternative [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090478/jquery-hashchange-event)